# In MongoDB, I have 3 config servers in mongo, if i kill one config server then sharding is not happening?

Tags: mongodb

I have made the below configuration set up.

1. 2 replica sets,
2. 3 config server,
3. 2 sharding

Here the problem is when I remove any one of the config servers, then data distribution is not happening

Answer (score 0):

If one or two config servers fail the cluster metadata moves to read-only mode. As shard configuration and chunk distribution is cluster metadata no modifications on cluster topology is allowed when the config servers are not all healthy.

In other words, because the `config` database is read-only in this state the balancer cannot write the results of chunk migrations to the `config.chunks` collection.

Comment: So writing will not happen in any mongod, if any one of the config server is killed.

Comment: Writes can happen to your own data, just not to the "config" database which is where chunk metadata is stored.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of MongoDB (3.2 and higher) you can run your config servers as a replica set, so if one fails they can still vote for a primary and remain fully functional - moving chunks etc.

See how to [migrate your config servers](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/upgrade-config-servers-to-replica-set/).